# While creating the sandbox I am getting the error like this?

Tags: apex, error, sandbox

[image]

While creating the sandbox I am getting the error like this?

Comment: Which class I have to select? We are creating the Developer Pro Sandbox

Answer (score 2):

That is not an error it is just an *Optional* input for a class that can be run when the sandbox is provisioned. As the messages says, leave it blank if you do not want to or do not know what it is.